# Feature Representation using CNN (Image Aesthetics)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I'm new to TensorFlow and i was able to use the below mentioned program for image classification. As Convolutional neural networks are arranged in layers, and each different layer captures information of a different kind. The first layers, which are close to the input, usually detect low-level information and deeper layers extract richer information.

Now, my **objective** is to compare images and learn the commonalities and differences between three images, that is, i want to learn a feature representation (say D) such as for 3 images (say I1,I2 and I3 - where I1 & I2 are aesthetically pleasing and I3 is not)

```
Distance(D(I1), D(I2)) < Distance(D(I1), D(I3))
```

What i figured out from this is pixel correlation plays an important role (correct me if i'm wrong).

**How can i achieve this? What are the steps involved in this process?**

*Code for Image Classification:*

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize


class vgg16:
    def __init__(self, imgs, weights=None, sess=None):
        self.imgs = imgs
        self.convlayers()
        self.fc_layers()
        self.probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.fc3l)
        if weights is not None and sess is not None:
            self.load_weights(weights, sess)


    def convlayers(self):
        self.parameters = []

        # zero-mean input
        with tf.name_scope('preprocess') as scope:
            mean = tf.constant([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 1, 3], name='img_mean')
            images = self.imgs-mean

        # conv1_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]



        # conv1_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv1_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool1
        self.pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv1_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool1')

        # conv2_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv2_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv2_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv2_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv2_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv2_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv2_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool2
        self.pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv2_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool2')

        # conv3_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv3_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv3_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv3_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv3_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool3
        self.pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv3_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool3')

        # conv4_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool3, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv4_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv4_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv4_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv4_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool4
        self.pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv4_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool4')

        # conv5_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool4, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv5_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv5_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv5_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv5_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool5
        self.pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv5_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool4')

    def fc_layers(self):
        # fc1
        with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
            shape = int(np.prod(self.pool5.get_shape()[1:]))
            fc1w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([shape, 4096],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc1b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            pool5_flat = tf.reshape(self.pool5, [-1, shape])
            fc1l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(pool5_flat, fc1w), fc1b)
            self.fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1l)
            self.parameters += [fc1w, fc1b]

        # fc2
        with tf.name_scope('fc2') as scope:
            fc2w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096, 4096],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc2b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            fc2l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self.fc1, fc2w), fc2b)
            self.fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2l)
            self.parameters += [fc2w, fc2b]

        # fc3
        with tf.name_scope('fc3') as scope:
            fc3w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096, 1000],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc3b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            self.fc3l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self.fc2, fc3w), fc3b)
            self.parameters += [fc3w, fc3b]

    def load_weights(self, weight_file, sess):
        weights = np.load(weight_file)
        keys = sorted(weights.keys())
        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            print (i, k, np.shape(weights[k]))
            sess.run(self.parameters[i].assign(weights[k]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3])
    vgg = vgg16(imgs, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)

    img1 = imread('img.jpg', mode='RGB')
    img1 = imresize(img1, (224, 224))

    prob = sess.run(vgg.probs, feed_dict={vgg.imgs: [img1]})[0]
    preds = (np.argsort(prob)[::-1])[0:5]
    for p in preds:
        print (class_names[p], prob[p])
```

*More clarification:*

how to write the code? because the aim is to find a mathematical space in which the distance between the two images that are aesthetically pleasing is less than the distance between an aesthetically pleasing one and one which is not. I'm not able to compute that.

Attributes to judge image aesthetics: interesting content, object emphasis, good lighting, color harmony, vivid color, shallow depth of f ield, motion blur, rule of thirds, balancing element, repetition, and symmetry.

Comment: You should look for Siamese networks in general, and the Triplet loss function.

Comment: @hbaderts something like this? https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/wiki/Triplet-loss-training-of-NN4

Comment: If you haven't seen these yet, I would check the following two tutorials: [DeepDream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws-ZbiFV1Ms&index=14&list=PL9Hr9sNUjfsmEu1ZniY0XpHSzl5uihcXZ)  and [Style Transfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoePx3QC5Js&index=15&list=PL9Hr9sNUjfsmEu1ZniY0XpHSzl5uihcXZ). They do not answer your direct question, but might be a good place to start.